# Laravel with SQLite returns error: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: SQRT"

Tags: laravel, sqlite

I use a SQLite database for a Laravel 8 project. I get an error message when I try to query it.

**Query:** `Model::selectRaw('col1,col2,col3,(6368 * SQRT(2*(1-cos(RADIANS(col1)))))')->get();`

**Error:** `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: SQRT`.

What am I doing wrong? Or is this query even possible with SQLite? Thank you for help!

Comment: I dont think that function is available in SQLlite. According to the docs (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_mathfunc.html#sqrt) there should be a function `sqrt()`. So without capital letters

Comment: @Merijndk The same error too. I think i have o enable first the math function. But i dont no how. Did you now?

Comment: You would have to build it yourself since there is no prebuild version including the math functions as far as I can see. Check this out https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html

Answer (score 0):

According to my comment:

It is possible, you could use `sqrt()`. But you need to make sure that you have the math library enabled according to the docs: sqlite.org/lang_mathfunc.html#sqrt "but are only active if the amalgamation is compiled using the -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS compile-time option."